# Check if file exists

Tags: .net, file-io

I have a page that allow user to upload a photo and the path of the photo would be save in db, which is something like this **'~/images/1288598614_house - Copy_000002.png'**.

So, i would like to check is the file exists when user retrieve the photo.

I have tried the code below:

```
Dim myPhoto As String = ~/images/1288598614_house - Copy_000002.png

If File.Exists(myPhoto) Then
   hfPhotoUploadPath.Value = myPhoto 
   imgPhoto.ImageUrl = hfPhotoUploadPath.Value
Else
   imgPhoto.ImageUrl = "~/images/default.jpg"
End If
```

but it's not working.....

Comment: Shouldn't ~ be replaced with a root path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to map that to a file path (example using C# syntax):

```
string localPath = Server.MapPath(myPhoto);
if(File.Exists(localPath)) {...}
```

**however** - the naked file system isn't *necessarily* the best option for this data - or at least, you would need to sanitize it before allowing upload of some file types. Also, you might (depending on scale) need to think about multiple servers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you need to replace the `~` with `Server.MapPath("~")`

```
Dim rootPath As String = Server.MapPath("~")
```

Comment: Correct, ~ is only applicable then used for paths displayed to the browser, not local file paths.